# how to select the first x elements in a binary search tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree

is there any existing algorithms for selecting the first x elements in a binary search tree? one way i could think of is to modify the tree traversal as follow:

```
int x = 0;

void inorder(tree* root, int *select_number, int *x){
if(root && select_number > x){
    inorder(root->left, select_number,x);
    //operations here
    (*x)++;
    inorder(root->right,select_number,x);
}
}
```

can this code work? is there a better way to do this? thank you so much!

Comment: a modified traversal is the way to do it. You need to test the code before posting.

Comment: what do you mean by first x elements? suppose x = 4; and our sorted list is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], do you want to retrieve [0,1,2,3] or just 3?

Comment: x is used to detect whether we have retrieved enough elements. it's auxiliary and should always be 0 we when start.